# .NET System.Process: when you redirect StandardError, console window receives no output

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, process, io-redirection

I want to get the error output of a console program in case it crashes. But I want the standard output to display in the console window.  However, if I redirect the standard error, nothing is output to the console window.

```
Dim p As New Process
p.StartInfo.Filename = filename
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
p.EnableRaisingEvents = True
p.Start
p.BeginReadErrorLine
```

So now if the launched process (a console program) crashes, I get the error output as expected.  However, the standard output is not visible in the console program.

I wrote a test program to launch.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        object m = null;
        string s = m.ToString();

    }
```

I expect to see the numbers 0 - 999 scroll in the console window and get the error output through the redirect, but I see nothing in the console window unless nothing is redirected.

I haven't found any questions dealing with this issue. Is this a defect or something i've overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing same, But I couldn't. Here's my code where I am redirecting only error but still I am able to see output on my console window:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        ExecuteCommand(@"cmd.exe", @"/c C:\Users\*****\Documents\Test\ConsoleApp1.exe");            
    }

    public static int ExecuteCommand(string exePath, string cmdText)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();            
        startInfo.FileName = exePath;
        startInfo.Arguments = cmdText;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;            
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;            
        process.Start();            
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();
        return process.ExitCode;
    }
}
```

Here's my output:

[image]

Am I doing something different form what You have tried?

Comment: I don't want to read standard output. I want standard output to go to the console window as normal. I only want to read standard error. But if I redirect standard error, it prevents standard output from going to the console.

Comment: I have updated my answer. ConsoleApp1.exe has exactly same codes which you have posted in question "Test Program".

Comment: I am not executing cmd.exe and launching my program from that.  Mine looks more like this:

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        ExecuteCommand(@"C:\Users\*****\Documents\Test\ConsoleApp1.exe");            
    }